# Can't find snippets.json file for Emmet plugin on Atom?

Tags: atom-editor, emmet

I updated Emmet to version 2.4.3 and can't seem to find the default snippets.json file. Previously I would just go to the package directory and it is at the root level, but now it's gone. Checked the DOCS and Emmet-Atom Github page but see no mention or update about the snippets.json missing. Has anyone come across this issue? Can anyone let me know where it is located on the updated version?